# Scrapy file, only running the initial start_urls instead of running though the whole list

Tags: python, scrapy

As the title states, I am trying to run my scrapy program, the issue I am running into is that it seems to be only returning the yield from the initial url (https://www.antaira.com/products/10-100Mbps).

I am unsure on where my program is not working, in my code I have also left some commented code on what I have attempted.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AntairaItem


class ProductJumperFix(scrapy.Spider):  # classes should be TitleCase

    name = 'productJumperFix'
    allowed_domains = ['antaira.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.antaira.com/products/10-100Mbps',
        'https://www.antaira.com/products/unmanaged-gigabit'
        'https://www.antaira.com/products/unmanaged-10-100Mbps-PoE'
        'https://www.antaira.com/products/Unmanaged-Gigabit-PoE'
        'https://www.antaira.com/products/Unmanaged-10-gigabit'
        'https://www.antaira.com/products/Unmanaged-10-gigabit-PoE'
    ]
    
    #def start_requests(self):
    #    yield scrappy.Request(start_urls, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        # iterate through each of the relative urls
        for url in response.xpath('//div[@class="product-container"]//a/@href').getall():
            product_link = response.urljoin(url)  # use variable
            yield scrapy.Request(product_link, callback=self.parse_new_item)

    def parse_new_item(self, response):
        for product in response.css('main.products'):
            items = AntairaItem() # Unique item for each iteration
            items['product_link'] = response.url # get the product link from response
            name = product.css('h1.product-name::text').get().strip()
            features = product.css(('section.features h3 + ul').strip()).getall()
            overview =   product.css('.products .product-overview::text').getall()
            main_image = response.urljoin(product.css('div.selectors img::attr(src)').get())
            rel_links = product.xpath("//script/@src[contains(., '/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl')]").getall()
            items['name'] = name,
            items['features'] = features,
            items['overview'] = overview,
            items['main_image'] = main_image,
            items['rel_links'] = rel_links,
            yield items
```

Thank you everyone!

Follow up question, for some reason when I run "scrapy crawl productJumperFix" im not getting any output from the terminal,not sure how to debug since I can't even see the output errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `start_requests` method:

For example:

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AntairaItem

class ProductJumperFix(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'productJumperFix'
    allowed_domains = ['antaira.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://www.antaira.com/products/10-100Mbps',
            'https://www.antaira.com/products/unmanaged-gigabit',
            'https://www.antaira.com/products/unmanaged-10-100Mbps-PoE',
            'https://www.antaira.com/products/Unmanaged-Gigabit-PoE',
            'https://www.antaira.com/products/Unmanaged-10-gigabit',
            'https://www.antaira.com/products/Unmanaged-10-gigabit-PoE',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath('//div[@class="product-container"]//a/@href').getall():
            product_link = response.urljoin(url)  # use variable
            yield scrapy.Request(product_link, callback=self.parse_new_item)

    def parse_new_item(self, response):
        for product in response.css('main.products'):
            items = AntairaItem() 
            items['product_link'] = response.url
            name = product.css('h1.product-name::text').get().strip()
            features = product.css(('section.features h3 + ul').strip()).getall()
            overview =   product.css('.products .product-overview::text').getall()
            main_image = response.urljoin(product.css('div.selectors img::attr(src)').get())
            rel_links = product.xpath("//script/@src[contains(., '/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl')]").getall()
            items['name'] = name,
            items['features'] = features,
            items['overview'] = overview,
            items['main_image'] = main_image,
            items['rel_links'] = rel_links,
            yield items
```

Comment: Hey @Alexander, I ran your code initially and it was working fine, I ran it again today and I am only receiving 34 items. I am expecting well over 100+ so I'm not sure what went wrong, could there be a settings where it limits the number of crawl? or perhaps its their website settings?

Comment: @Shadobladez what do the logs say?  it might be the website blocking you because it detects that the scraper is not a human

Comment: That's a problem that I have been having in this project, I'm not certain why, but I am not receiving any verbose or logs on my program. I'm honestly not certain where the log file would be located as when I created my project, the default log folder did not get generated. 

EDIT - although I do feel like I may be getting blocked on their side, when I do run it on smaller/individual files it looks like it went through successfully.

Comment: The logs are what appear in your terminal when you run your spider.  they don't get output to a file unless you tell it to in the settings

Comment: Okay, then yea, I have not been able to see any logs, which is probably why I have been having more issues then possibly should have...

Comment: I just ran the program with only this link - https://www.antaira.com/products/Rackmount-Switches/LMX-3228G-10G-SFP-AA - and I got back 22 items when the expected should be 29.
EDIT UPDATE - I ran it again, and it worked, I'm trying to find where the inconsistency is - also found in settings why I couldn't see the logs, apparently they were being tossed into a tmp file. So i can see the logs again.

Comment: Since this answer was successfully answered previously, I'll create a new one with the most up-to-date files and the log out.

Comment: @Shadobladez  I will look into this soon

Comment: I have created the new question here, thank you very much again!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73367452/scrapy-file-is-not-running-through-the-list-of-items-updated-code